# finding and proving where function is...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

So I have this function:

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} ( 2 \sqrt{-1-x}-1)^{\frac{1}{4^{-x}-16}} & \quad \text{if } x<{-2}\\ - \frac{\pi}{4}x & \quad \text{if } -2\leq x \leq 1 \\ \frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\ln(2x^2-1)} &\quad  \text{if } x > 1\\ \end{cases} $

And I have to write down where this function is continuous and where it is not.
And I also have to prove it.

so my first thought is, that it probably is continous between -2 and 1, while it's linear there. And because $\ln$ and $\sin$ are both continous, I think that for x > 1 it should be continuous also, but I could be mistanken.
So any help would be appreciated.

And by the way: we use $\ln$ as natural logarithm in my country, I hope it is not confusing, because soemtiems it is used only $\log$.

Comment: Start by checking whether $\lim_{x \rightarrow -2} f(x)$ from the first case of the definition is equal to $f(-2)$ from the second case of the definition. Similarly for the transition from the second to the third cases.

Comment: i doubt that limit of first case will be $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: The first branch makes a problem. How could the expression generate something like $\frac \pi 2$ for $x=-2$ ? I guess that this is the trap !!

Comment: yeah, that's what i thought too, and i guess there is a theorem that states, that it is not continous for $x<-2$
and by the way, can anyone help me with limit of 3rd case?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Your function is **continuous on** $(-\infty,-2)$ being composition of continuous functions.

As $x \to -2^-$, we have
$$
 ( 2 \sqrt{-1-x}-1)^{\frac{1}{4^{-x}-16}} \to e^{\frac1{32\ln 2}}
$$
As $x \to -2^+$, we have
$$
- \frac{\pi}{4}x \to  \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$ Since $\displaystyle e^{\frac1{32\ln 2}} \neq  \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $f$ is **not continuous at** $x=-2$.

As $x \to 1^-$, we have
$$
- \frac{\pi}{4}x \to  -\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$
As $x \to 1^+$, we have
$$
\frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\ln(2x^2-1)} = \frac{-\pi  (x-1)+O (x-1)^3}{4 (x-1)+O (x-1)^2} \to  -\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$ Thus $f$ is **continuous on** $(-2,+\infty)$.

Comment: I think we didn't use that $O$ yet, so can you plese write the answer with limit, without using l'hospitalet rule or taylor series, becasue it's only the first semester of calculus, and it's forbidden to use some of techniques.
I would really appreciate if you can write down limits for first and 3rd case, if it's not to much to ask.
thankyou for the help thought.

Comment: We can only use changing the limit so it is simmilar or same as 10 that we already proved. they are really basic.

Comment: @user246608 You are right. We may only use standard limits as $\frac{\sqrt{1+u}-1}u \to \frac12$, $\frac{\sin u}u \to 1$, $\frac{\ln(1+u)}u \to 1$, as $u \to 0$. With the change of variable $u=x+2$ or $u=x-1$.... Thanks.

Comment: you could edit the answer so it is solved the proper(if you consider limited usage of analysis) way.